# Getting a Image to Resize Responsively Before It's Edges Are Reached in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a small image in my project that I would like to resize responsively any time the resolution changes.  I am currently using the class "img-responsive".  With this class, the picture doesn't start resizing until the window reaches its edge.  In this case, since it's a relatively small picture, this never happens.

Is there a built-in Bootstrap class I can use to have the image resize responsively at all times?

Comment: What is the image size? Do you have it inside a container? It looks like the `img-responsive` contains down to very small size: http://bootply.com/88562

Comment: @Skelly Size is 200x300.  If you look at the fiddle you provided, you'll notice the image doesn't start resizing until a certain point when you start decreasing the width of your browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using JavaScript

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() < 1100){
        var width = $(window).width();
        var ceiling_width = 1100;
        var difference = ceiling_width - width;
        var decrease = difference * 0.2345;
        var full_logo_width = 404;
        var new_logo_width = full_logo_width - decrease;
        $("#my_logo").css({"width": new_logo_width});
    }
});
```

If the browser's width gets lower than 1100px then the picture will start shrinking.  My image has a width of 404px by default (if the browser loads with a width of more than 1100px).  I wanted the smallest possible width for the image to be a little over 200px.  The per pixel decrease to per window width decrease variable (0.2345 in this case) was calculated based on this.  I used the following CSS to set an upper and lower limit for the image's width.

```
#my_logo{
     max-width: 404px;
     min-width: 210px;
}
```